# How to remove ui-sref active from parent when going to a child state

Tags: ui-sref

I have a navigation bar in which first option is of the parent state and other opitions are for child states.I have used ui-sref-active to highlight which state is active. Now when I switch from one state to another the parent state is always highlighted along with the child state.
Any suggestions how to solve this?

```
 <li ui-sref-active="nav-session-page">
        <a ui-sref="dashboard">... </a>
 </li>
 <li  ui-sref-active="nav-candidate-page">
      <a ui-sref="dashboard.candidate" >..</a>
 </li>
 <li ui-sref-active="nav-interviewer-page">
      <a ui-sref="dashboard.interviewer">..</a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I have solved this problem, I have used **ui-sref-active-eq** for this purpose.What it does is that only the state which is active is highlighted and all other states remain the same event the parent state also.